# Is compass sensor work on Android 2.3.3 with Qt 5.2.1?

Tags: android, qt, qt5, compass-geolocation

[This table](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/compatmap.html) says that it doesn't.

But some references from the internet says that it works with Necessitas.

I can not check it by myself now, so i'm asking it here.

Is the compass currently working on Android 2.3.3 with Qt 5.2.1?

Comment: you can always fallback to the android ndk

Comment: @SebastianLange is compass available through NDK?

Answer (score -1):

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Reference site: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html

Comment: It is not for compass: «For example, the Calendar Provider APIs were added in Android 4.0 (API level 14). If your app cannot function without these APIs, you should declare API level 14 as your app's minimum supported version like this:»